# datepicker codeigniter 2.2 problem

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

hi im trying to integrate a jquery datepicker to my codeigniter project.. the problem is that i cant get it to work .. my source code came from http://view.jquery.com/tags/ui/latest/demos/functional/#ui.datepicker
ok heres my code:

view:

```
<srcipt>
$("#formatted").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: $.datepicker.ISO_8601, 
    showOn: "both", 
    buttonImage: "templates/images/calendar.gif", 
    buttonImageOnly: true 
});
</script>
<form action="add" method="post" class="form label-inline uniform" />
<input type="text" size="30" value="" id="formatted"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-grey" value="Add User"/>
</form>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**
i already added all the js sources but its still not working

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/misc/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/facebox.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.visualize.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**
created a sample view page for datepicker.. still not working even the link for the image is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/misc/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/facebox.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.visualize.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script>
$("#formatted").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: $.datepicker.ISO_8601, 
    showOn: "both", 
    buttonImage: "http://pgoadmin.com/assets/images/calendar.gif", 
    buttonImageOnly: true 
});
</script>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" value="" id="formatted"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load in jQuery UI to use the date picker

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.js

Dont forget the images and CSS as well:

http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jquery before you start using it. Try moving the JS code below the jquery tag.

And as Wes says, you need to include jquery UI datepicker component as well.

Also, and this maybe a typo, your tag says "sricpt" instead of "script".

Comment: i already added all the js links,,loaded the jquery-ui.js but its still not working

Comment: Did you move the jquery tag up the page to before your JS code like I said?

Answer (score 1):

and don't forget to add base_url(); to your js paths

e.g.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
```