# Datepicker using jquery in codeigniter not working

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

i want to use date picker in my view in codeignigter. Here is my code but it is not working. please help

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<div>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
</div>
```

But when i am using it in html page it is working where i am doing wrong ? help me to find.

Comment: see console, for any errors

Comment: code is running perfect dude .whats the problem ???

Comment: how can i see console in codeignigter

Comment: @RavindraShekhawat code is running in html but when i am integrating it in codeigniter view file it is showing nothing

Comment: press ctrl+shift+j to check console in your browser to get the js errors if there any

Comment: @user2249227 i think may be there are multiple jquery is getting included of different versions.please check view source

Comment: may be it is some conflicts, etc. It works - check this out http://jsfiddle.net/KpArm/

Comment: may be your source of jquery file is not correct please check view source or resources in developer tool . you can also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039586/datepicker-codeigniter-2-2-problem?rq=1 question . almost same as your .

Comment: now it is working. it was some conflicts issue. thank you all for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and provide the source

here is reference

> http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save hours that I spent.
follow the article. worked for me.
    
use class instead of id and add following script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

https://hiteshkumarsofat.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/use-of-bootstrap-date-picker-for-codeigniter/
just replace the commas with ' and " with the ones he used.